# Cómo ocultar las imagenes que no cargan

Tags: php, javascript, html

como podria ocultar las imagenes que no cargan correctamente.. aqui les dejo tres imagenes, una que me carga bien y la otra no.. Estas imagenes son de un producto, si se fijan bien antes del .jpg del href de la etiqueta IMG hay un número y seguido un guion (-) que indica que muestre la imagen 1,2,3.. etc.

/imagenescatalogo/8469-1.jpg
/imagenescatalogo/8469-2.jpg
/imagenescatalogo/8469-5.jpg

No siempre la imagen con -5 sale con errores en otros productos, asi que debo ocultar esta imagen en caso de que me salga con error.

Buen dia!

EJEMPLO..

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Imagen 1</th>
    <th>Imagen 2</th>
    <th>Imagen 3</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="img1" src="https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-1.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99" width="84" height="84" alt=""></td>
    <td><img id="img1" src="https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-2.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99" width="84" height="84" alt=""></td>
    <td><img id="img1" src="https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-5.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99" width="84" height="84" alt=""></td>
    <td> 
      <h4>
        El link de esta imagen está bien, solo que no existe en el sv y la quiero ocultar.
      </h4> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que pruebes la url de la imagen original `http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-5.jpg` con una petición ajax, de manera de detectar cuáles devolvieron un error 404. De la manera como lo tienes ahora, ese error lo maneja el generador de thumbnails y siempre te devolverá un header 200.

Comment: @amenadiel ¿Cómo se haria?

Answer (score 3):

Hay un evento para las imagenes cuando no cargan, y llames a un `function` para decidir que hacer:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Tú código no es funcional, no deberias colocarlo en un snippet

Comment: editado* gracias por la corrección

Answer (score 2):

Algo de JQuery puede solucionar tu problema con el evento on error, pero para eso tienes que mover el atributo "src" a la porcion en JQuery tambien,

a proposito, super mala practica tener varios elementos bajo la misma ID, si quieres seleccionarlos a la vez lo ideal es tener diferentes IDs pero la misma clase.

`$("#img1")
    .on('error', function() {$(this).visible=false;})
    .attr("src", $("https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-1.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99").attr("src"))`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#img1")
    .on('error', function() 
    {
     $(img1)[0].style.display = "none";
   })
   .attr("src", $("#img1Hidden")[0].src);
 
  $("#img2")
    .on('error', function() {
     $(img2)[0].style.display = "none";
    })
   .attr("src", $("#img2Hidden")[0].src);
 
  $("#img3")
    .on('error', function() {
     $(img3)[0].style.display = "none";
   })
   .attr("src", $("#img3Hidden")[0].src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Imagen 1</th>
    <th>Imagen 2</th>
    <th>Imagen 3</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="img1Hidden" src="https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-1.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99" width="84" height="84" alt="" style="display:none">
    <img id="img1" width="84" height="84" alt="">
    
    </td>
    <td><img id="img2Hidden" src="https://www.dyna.com.co/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://190.248.128.69:8002/public/imagenescatalogo/8469-2.jpg&w=350&h=350&far=1&bg=ffffff&q=99" width="84" height="84" alt="" style="display:none">
     <img id="img2" width="84" height="84" alt="">
    </td>
    <td><img id="img3Hidden" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png" width="84" height="84" alt="" style="display:none">
       <img id="img3" width="84" height="84" alt="">
    </td>
    <td> 
      <h4>
        El link de esta imagen está bien, solo que no existe en el sv y la quiero ocultar.
      </h4> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Por alguna razon el API de jquery no funciona